# PayPal payments - refunding orders

Tags: php, zend-framework, paypal, paypal-ipn

Does anyone here know how to refund money to users payed from my e-commerce site orders?

I mean .. I can surely go to my PP business account to refund them manually, but I would like to know if PP API supports some kind of dynamic refund directly from my site..

Answer (score 0):

It looks possible read this.

[PayPal API Docs](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APRefund)

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code and API for your task.

```
$nvpStr = "&TRANSACTIONID=$transactionID&REFUNDTYPE=$refundType&CURRENCYCODE=$currencyID";
```

and then call this function:

```
$httpParsedResponseAr = PPHttpPost('RefundTransaction', $nvpStr);
```

for more details regarding that you can use below link :
https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/nvp_RefundTransaction_php.txt